# How to find trend line with high and low line?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I have been using reliance datasets. My datasets look like this.

```
Date        Open    High        Low         Close       Adj Close   year_month
2019-04-15  1345.0  1348.949951 1335.000000 1340.150024 1332.769409 2019-04
2019-04-16  1345.0  1360.000000 1340.000000 1343.750000 1336.349609 2019-04
2019-04-18  1375.0  1389.750000 1365.000000 1385.949951 1378.317139 2019-04
2019-04-22  1360.0  1367.000000 1341.300049 1345.349976 1337.940796 2019-04
2019-04-23  1348.0  1373.000000 1346.000000 1363.849976 1356.338867 2019-04
```

This is my code but the x axis looks messy if we see the graph

```
f,ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('Price')
ax1.set_title('Original Plot')
ax1.plot('Date', 'Adj Close', data = df);
```

Output:-

[image: Output1]

So i use another feature but the figure is not as same as before.

```
f,ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 5))
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('Price')
ax1.set_title('Original Plot')
ax1.plot('year_month', 'Adj Close', data = df);
```

Output:-
[image: output2]

Expected Output:- (Note:- It is just an example. This figure is not related with my datasets)

[image: output3]

Hope to get soon response. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to change labeling of X axis, but your `ax1.plot()` plots different data.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html, apply `myLocator = mticker.MultipleLocator(4)` it would help

Comment: The dates you plotted are for 2019-2020, while the example shown, is for 2008 until 2017, also the y-ticks seems to be on different scales, are actually plotting the same data?

Comment: @jcaliz my expected output is just an example. What i wanted is high and low line just like expected output with the x-axis of second figure. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is just in determining the **ticks** over the x-axis. I have created a [dummy data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ybXf_eugRG98Yj0qEUKg5A1Yu91wf2Gz) to prove my point.

Here is how the graph looked like before setting `xticks`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
f,ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 5))
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('Price')
ax1.set_title('Original Plot')
ax1.plot('Date', 'Price', data = df)
```

[image]

And here is the graph after setting `xticks`; you can do so just by writing the following two lines before `plt.show()`

```
ax1.set_xticks(ax1.get_xticks()[::30])
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

[image]

Hope this answers your question!!

Comment: God bless you man. And how can i get high and low line just like an expected output?

Comment: I don't what these two lines represent, do you know the technical term?

Comment: @AnwarvicThe high line represent the high price of the adj close and low line represent the low price of the adj close.

Comment: I don't think so, the high price or the low price can be represented by a dot. For sure, this line passes through the highest price, but not just that

Comment: Thanksfor the response bro.

Comment: Glad I could help!!